# iPhone: Valid signing identity not found annoying error

Tags: iphone, keychain, code-signing-certificate

I know that this is very common problem and I have gone through almost all the similar threads out here but no luck! This started happening after I renewed my membership with Apple!

I have confirm that I have private and public key in Key Chain, the required certificate listed under My Certificate, have my development certificate, and AWDR certificated installed but still under XCode organizer I get message saying "profile doesn't match any valid certificate/private key pair in default key chain". I also restarted mac twice.

Also I have confirmed everything mentioned at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1618/_index.html

What else to do? I have been scratching my head since last 3-4 hours now without any luck!

Thanks.

Comment: I have the exact same problem. But I ignored it and was able to sing my application with an application provisioning profile while uploading to the app store. What can you not do?

Comment: is you certificate under the login keychain ?

Comment: @Cyprian I am not able to build my app!

Comment: Have you made the provisioning profile by selecting the correct certificate . Because this error generally comes when your provisioning profile is not accepted by the system as it could not find a valid certificate to prove the authenticity of profile .

Comment: Yah I have been doing it and working fine. I returned from one month holiday and everything seems to be messed up! I have created everything new apple id, provisioning profile, and push notification certificate....all looks good in key chain but Xcode organizer is not picking them!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After so much pain I exported keys from other MAC where it works and imported on my Machine and **RESTARTED MAC** then it started working!

I could have revoked the certificates and create them from scratch so while generating CA Authority request certificate private keys would be generated on my machine. Learn to save these keys in .p12 format on shared location so that you simply need to double click to install it again!

Answer (score 0):

You could try and have a look at the project.pbxproj located inside the .xcodeproj package (open it by right clicking and select 'Show package contents'). Search the file for PROVISIONING_PROFILE and make sure everything checks out to the correct profiles. I've had problems in the past when Xcode doesn't really update this file but when I do it manually it works.

Comment: they are blank because it doesn't allow me to select my certificate due to no valid certificate/private key pair found error. I have selected iPhone Developer for signing profile and it doesn;t match any!